# Insert temporaly image over widget

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, qt-creator, pyqt5

I want to insert an animation or image over a `tabWidget` with `listWidget` in it if the program is started for the first time or some specific setting is not set. For now it looks like this:
[image: ScreenShot]

I want to replace the whole `tabWidget` without having to create it again, so just placing image or animation over the widget will work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tab widget was `ui->myTab`, then you can add a an widget over the tab using `QWidget::setGeometry(x, y, width, height)`. For example, to add a button over the tab widget at position (5,10) with a size of 20x20:

```
QPushButton * refreshButton = new QPushButton(ui->myTab);
refreshButton ->setGeometry(5,10,20,20);
```